# How to replace an image in Image folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am uploading an image and saving it in a folder `Image` I have created. When I upload second image it must replace the image already existing in the folder. Means `Image` folder must always contain just one image. How will I do it??

Secondly how will I access the image from another different page? Like, suppose I uploaded the file from `Page1.aspx` and I want to show the same image on `Page2.aspx` ??

Language I'm using is C#.

Comment: Save the uploaded file with **identical** filename. Say /images/image.jpg

Comment: @Arush, what finally did you get?

Comment: I did same as @AVD...finally I got a folder, say Images contaning just 1 image. No matter how many the user had uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to look at this example: [ASP.NET forms - Upload image to DB](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/fileupload-control-save-images-database.html).

One other way would be storing image in folder and accessing it through relative path.

You may also want to look at this post: [Best way to create a folder and upload a image to that folder in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740342/1437962)

Comment: I have written the code for uploading an image. That was not my question either. Thanks.

Comment: OK Arush, you may want to look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/740354/1437962  Also hope u will not forget to vote for my effort to help.