# how can I upload an image to server and save its path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to be able to upload an image to the server but instead of saving the image as byte in the database I want to save the path so that in the view page I call the image by it's path.also the image when uploaded it should be uploaded in a certain folder if folder not found create one.all this should be using MVC5 any help is really appreciated

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: MVC 5 that is available in c#

Comment: Which language/framework? What have you already tried? Where are you facing the issue?

Comment: actually I don't know how to code it I was looking for some help in coding and comments

Comment: These links will solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978717/how-to-upload-an-image-file-to-active-directory-user-profile-in-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740342/best-way-to-create-a-folder-and-upload-a-image-to-that-folder-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what language you want to do this in but this is the desired implementation method behind saving photos to a database. (basically what your saying)

1. Photo is compressed
2. Photo is sent to server
3. Server's api handles the storage of the file into folder
4. Save folderpath+'filename' into database

Here is a PHP method upload(), part of the server API to handle steps 3 and 4

Found on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22)

```
//upload API
function upload($id, $photoData, $title) {

    // index.php passes as first parameter to this function $_SESSION['IdUser']
    // $_SESSION['IdUser'] should contain the user id, if the user has already been authorized
    // remember? you store the user id there in the login function
    if (!$id) errorJson('Authorization required');

    // check if there was no error during the file upload
    if ($photoData['error']==0) {

        // insert the details about the photo to the "photos" table
        $result = query("INSERT INTO photos(IdUser,title) VALUES('%d','%s')", $id, $title);
        if (!$result['error']) {

            // fetch the active connection to the database (it's initialized automatically in lib.php)
            global $link;

            // get the last automatically generated ID in the photos table
            $IdPhoto = mysqli_insert_id($link);

            // move the temporarily stored file to a convenient location
            // your photo is automatically saved by PHP in a temp folder
            // you need to move it over yourself to your own "upload" folder
            if (move_uploaded_file($photoData['tmp_name'], "upload/".$IdPhoto.".jpg")) {

                // file moved, all good, generate thumbnail
                thumb("upload/".$IdPhoto.".jpg", 180);

                //just print out confirmation to the iPhone app
                print json_encode(array('successful'=>1));
            } else {
                //print out an error message to the iPhone app
                errorJson('Upload on server problem');
            };

        } else {
            errorJson('Upload database problem.'.$result['error']);
        }
    } else {
        errorJson('Upload malfunction');
    }
}
```